# Pandas : Find which index in array is equals to last element of other array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, indexing, find

I have two columns with arrays which are generated from two others

```
mf['FV_array'] = mf['FV'].str.split()
mf['MT_array'] = mf['MT'].str.split()
```

and now what i am tryin to do is find which `mf['MT_array']` index in every row is equals to last index in every `mf['FV_array']`, a lot of my probes with index function did not work.

Example what i would like to do :

```
FV_array                                |   MT_array     |  Result

['Something','John','Doe','is','there']   ['John','Doe']      2
```

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: Provide your data and the output expect. Otherwise is hard to help you. Kindly read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply()` to call `index()` on the elements in each row.

```
mf['Result'] = mf.apply(lambda row: row['FV_array'].index(row['MT_array'][-1]) if row['MT_array'][-1] in row['FV_array'] else None, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank You! That looks to work great, unfortunetelly i did not foresee that will be a few cases when there is no match and it causes ValueErrror : xxx is not in list and interrupt code, maybe do you have an idea how to return none in this kind of situation? :)

Comment: I added a conditional expression